# Is there any option to change auto-implementation TypeScript language in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm woring with VSCode and TypeScript and using many interfaces that refer to eachother. So the VSCode's `Implement interface` hotfix function is very useful, but the end result is not perfect.

Here is what I get now:

```js
import { CertificationOutgoingInvoiceUIFieldsInterface } from './certification-outgoing-invoice.interface';

export class CertificationOutgoingInvoice implements CertificationOutgoingInvoiceUIFieldsInterface {
  deviza_id: import("../../../base-model/base-data-type.model").ID;
  deviza_exchange_type_id: import("../../../base-model/base-data-type.model").ID;
  payment_type_id: import("../../../base-model/base-data-type.model").ID;
  foreign_invoice_id: string;
  foreign_api_status: import("../../../base-model/base-data-type.model").ForeignAPIStatus;
  foreign_api_messages: string[];
  is_installment_enabled: boolean;
  installments: import("../../../invoice/installment/invoice-installment.interface").InvoiceInstallmentInterface[];
  files: import("../../../file/file-model.interface").FileModelInterface[];
}
```

Actually two problems are here.

1. I set it up earlier in tslint to use apostrophe instead of double quotes. It's working fine if I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> combination to include an import line.
2. This end result would be much more handy:

```js
import { CertificationOutgoingInvoiceUIFieldsInterface } from './certification-outgoing-invoice.interface';
import { ID, ForeignAPIStatus } from 'src/app/models/base-model/base-data-type.model';
import { InvoiceInstallmentInterface } from 'src/app/models/invoice/installment/invoice-installment.interface';
import { FileModelInterface } from 'src/app/models/file/file-model.interface';

export class CertificationOutgoingInvoice implements CertificationOutgoingInvoiceUIFieldsInterface {
  deviza_id: ID;
  deviza_exchange_type_id: ID;
  payment_type_id: ID;
  foreign_invoice_id: string;
  foreign_api_status: ForeignAPIStatus;
  foreign_api_messages: string[];
  is_installment_enabled: boolean;
  installments: InvoiceInstallmentInterface[];
  files: FileModelInterface[];
}
```

This is much more cleaner. Now I need to spend time to fix the auto-implement's result to this.

Is there any option to get this end result in VSCode?